# Taylor Expansion of a function that maps matrices to scalars

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider first-order taylor approximations

For $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(\tilde x) \approx f(x) + (\tilde x - x)f'(x)$

For $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) \approx f(\mathbf
{x}) + (\mathbf{\tilde{x}} - \mathbf{x})^T\nabla_xf(\mathbf{x})$

What shall be the corresponding expansion for a $f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \to \mathbb{R}$?
$f(\mathbf{\tilde{X}}) \approx f(\mathbf
{X}) + ?$

Comment: ${\rm R}^{n\times m}\simeq  {\rm R}^{nm}$

Answer (score 2):

Basing on the fact that $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\simeq \mathbb{R}^{nm}$ we get for $X=\{x_{ij}\}$
$$\displaylines{f(\tilde{X})\approx f(X)+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m{\partial f\over \partial x_{ij}}(X)\,(\tilde{x}_{ij}-x_{ij})\\ =f(X)+{\rm Tr}\,[(\tilde{X}-X)^T\nabla f(X)]}$$ where $\nabla f(X)=\displaystyle\left\{{\partial f\over \partial x_{ij}}(X)\right\}.$